# PHP Jquery Wall Post

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-wall

I'm trying to build a post-to-wall system. I followed a tutorial and it looks like I'm fairly close. However, loads of warnings come up when I post instead of the actual post. Do I need to setup a database somwewhere? I've never done much with PHP or databases, so excuse my ignorance.

http://beulahprint.ie/facebook_wallpost_system/

Comment: Here's the tutorial I followed:
http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-style-wallpost-and-comments-system-using-jquery-ajax-and-php-reloaded/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on whether you have underlying access to the machine that you are doing your development on.

If it is a linux machine and you are able to log into it then the following command will work for Red Hat (and it's derivatives: fedora, centos, etc...) as well as deban based systems such as ubuntu:

```
mysql --version
```

If this command reports some form of error they you will probably need to install mysql with one of the following commands:

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
```

The `sudo` part makes you superuser so that you may install the software (not everyone) can install software you know. When you have run this command the computer will go through all the normal steps to install the software, but it will ask you a number of questions like: what would you like the root password to be? what IP is mysql going to run on? Luckily MySql fills most of these in by default.

If you are running on windows then it is just a matter of downloading the installation file from the mysql website, double clicking the .exe, and following the installation steps.

Good luck!

*EXTRA: If you are looking for an easy way to access your mysql database you can't go far wrong with 'MySQL GUI Tools', just google it.*

Comment: I'm running on Windows Vista. I downloaded MySQL workbench, is this what I need? What do I do once I have the interface open though? Do I need to create my own database? How do I do that?

Comment: forget workbench for now. you need to download `MySQL Community Server` and during installation make sure you select `Standard Configuration` leave the checkbox checked for `Service Options Dialog` (it makes sure MySQL starts up every time you turn on the machine) and enter a password for the root account in the `The Security Options Dialog` window. After this you should be good to go. also the following maybe of some help: http://www1.nyist.net/mysqldoc/en/installing.html

Comment: This is gonna sound really dumb...but I've downloaded and installed the community server and followed your instructions. So what do I do now?

Comment: I have just read the tutorial you referenced and I'm guessing you have yet to create the tables for the database you are going to be working on. So... `MySQL GUI Tools` should have installed `MySQL Query Browser`. Open it up, for `Server Hostname` enter `localhost`, for `User` enter `root`, for `password` enter your password, and leave `Default Schema` blank. Click `Connect`. enter the command `create database facebookwall;` and then click `execute`. Then cut'n'paste the `CREATE TABLE` text from the comments (because he got it wrong at the top of the tutorial) and click `excute` again

Comment: Then in your php `$dbname = 'facebookwall';`

Comment: Ok just to clear things up. So far, I have downloaded that wall tutorial, setup a hosting account on reg365,set-up a database on reg365 with a hostname, username and password (they never gave me an option to setup a table). I have workbench 5.2 on my computer. I opened that, clicked "new connection", host = mssql.namesco.net, user = colm, password = *********. Now, Workbench says I cannot connect to that database.

Comment: because your tutorial files are on a web server and `workbench` and `Query Browser` are on your computer at home I would recommend installing XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) installed on your home PC and work through the tutorials on you home PC

Comment: ok Ive downloaded xampp and got it working. Now I got rid of the errors, but when I post a message.....nothing happens! I'll keep trying stuff though and hopefully figure it out, I'll stop annoying you with my simplicity! :) Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: Yo sevenarths, which part of the create table text did he get wrong? The one from the comments looks identical to the origninal one to me? At the momnent I have my wall connecting, but when I post something nothing happens....so I'm guessing I have the wrong create table text in?

Comment: Read further down the tutorial and your find that the `create table` text is wrong at the top of the tutorial. Right click on the table in `Query Browser` and drop it before you re-create it

Comment: ok I think I never named my database "facebookwall", so I created a new one. Still have no clue what you mean about the databse being corrected lower down in the tutorial, I see some guy posted the database tables again in the comment section, but it looks identical to the original table? So now when I post something on my site, the following error is given. Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\facebook_wallpost_system\posts.php on line 71

Answer (score 0):

All of the errors you are seeing are due to a missing database and the inclusion of db files. You'll need to connect to the database (using PDO or MySQLi) and update it with the content you are entering. Looks like you are about halfway there.

Comment: I downloaded Mysql workbench? I haven't a clue what I'm looking at though. Which database do I need to connect to? And how do I do that?

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqldatabase.php - this is a good starting point to learning about databases and how they are created, maintained and used.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial man! I have created a database and I added the php code to my site to connect to the database. Here is the code I added:

<?php
 $dbhost = 'mssql.namesco.net';
 $dbuser = 'root';
 $dbpass = 'QWERTYCOLM1';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'prayerwebsite';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>

The guys at reg365.com say the host name is correct. But my site is still giving an error. Any ideas?

Colm

Comment: try using `'localhost'` for your `$dbhost`, else verify all credentials and db name is correct. Also, change your password and don't post your real one here (if that is it.)

Comment: I've tried all that and changed my password. All the info looks correct to me, it still won't work though. Here is my code:

<?php
 $dbhost = 'mssql.namesco.net';
 $dbuser = 'colm';
 $dbpass = '**************';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'prayerwebsite';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>

Comment: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mssql.namesco.net' (10060) in \\nas01\nas\b\e\beulahprint.ie\web\facebook_wallpost_system\dbcon.php on line 6
Error connecting to mysql

Comment: Line 6 = $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

Comment: Are you on a host or a local machine? I'd refer you to the other answer on this page. You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server.

Comment: Not sure, the site is live. I have a hosting package with reg365 setup and I have a database created on that package.

Comment: I've just noticed that the error says Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mssql.namesco.net' (10060) in \\nas01\nas\b\e\beulahprint.ie\web\facebook_wallpost_system\dbcon.php..........there seems to be a \web\ in there that's not in my site's url. Could that be the problem? If so, any ideas why the \web\ is there?